# KnpMenu - Is it possible to use only one menu tree for my web application?

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

I am using KnpMenuBundle in a Symfony2 project. I wonder if it is possible and good to only use one tree menu in my App. It would have 3-4 levels. I don't wan't to have sub-menus but I wan't to use the same menu to create my breadcrumb. Also, is it possible to display the menu on the second and still without its sub-menus?

My tree menu would look like this :

```
- Item 1
    - Item 1-1
    - Item 1-2
    - Item 1-2
- Item 2
    - Item 2-1
    - Item 2-2
    - Item 2-3
        - Item 2-3-1
        - Item 2-3-2
        - Item 2-3-3
- Item 3
    - Item 3-1
    - Item 3-2
```

And here is my use cases :

**Main menu**

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

**Second menu**

```
Item 2-1
Item 2-2
Item 2-3
```

**Breadcrumb**

```
Item 2 > Item 2-3 > Item 2-3-1
```

Thanks for your help!